# How to pass javascript variable to a PHP file in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

I just need to know what all I need to do for passing my JavaScript variable to the PHP file.

All I have done till now is created a form which inputs some values alongside that I have also a JavaScript variable which I need to pass to the same location as of the form.

So how do I achieve it in Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery ajax method, in which you can pass you js variable and use it in php on any other server side scripting language.

[Ajax Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    method: 'post',
    data:
    {
        variable1 : value1,     // you can use these variable in process.php file
        variable2 : value2
    },
    success: function(response)
    {

    }
});
```